# IIS 7.5 Routing Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I'm using routing in my asp.net 2.0 project, and when I go to go to the website I get the error:

```
Module *IIS Web Core*
Notification **MapRequestHandler**
Handler **StaticFile**
```

I had first thought that it was because of default documenting being wrong, but after going to another link that the routing handles, I had gotten the same error.

The most information I have is that I have a Web.sitemap file, a App_global.asax.dll and a App_global.asax.compiled.

From all projects I've worked on in the past, I've used Global.asax but I'm missing that from the project directory.
After doing research, I had added the MIME type of the sitemap file, but it had still not fixed the problem. 
I had also tried looking for HotFixes of this problem but wasn't able to accomplish anything.

I had also tried [this](http://blog.tjitjing.com/index.php/2010/09/asp-net-routing-gives-404-error.html) but it hadn't helped, though all of the problems match the one I'm having.

Comment: Are u using Routing on ASP.Net 2.0??? and is it a web Application or MVC? Third when do you get the error, What are you trying to do

Comment: Yes I am using routing on ASP.NET. It is a web application, and I'm simply just trying to load the home page without the 'index.aspx.' I've also gotten it when trying to load user profiles

Comment: Not sure if you can use Routing on ASP.Net 2.0. And here by routing I mean clean URL. If you just want to navigate to page.aspx on load you have to set it as starting page check here http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Comment: Well I know all of it is already working because before we switched servers and upgraded to a newer version of IIS, everything worked fine

Comment: OK can you dig into the IIS Log and post the error message from there then. also can you post an example of the url you are visiting and confirm is it ASP.Net 2.0 (i.e. From Visual studio 2005) also you mentioned something about switching what did you switch and from what to what? please be more explicit

Comment: I did more research but wasn't able to find the IIS logs. Also, an example of the link is http://www.exmample.com/User

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49922/discussion-between-jack-m-and-destiny-dawn)

Comment: @DestinyDawn have you tried this [solution](http://serverfault.com/a/404321).

Comment: You can ask this question also [here](http://serverfault.com/).